# Cannot read (or find?) ResourceBundle

Tags: jasper-reports, resourcebundle

Below is my project structure.

```
Project
   |
   |--src
   |    |
   |    |--com
   |    |    |
   |    |    |--jasper
   |    |         |
   |    |         |--JasperDemo.java
   |    |
   |    |--i18n.properties
   |
   | 
   |--Arabic.jrxml
```

In the properties file there is a key **text1.paragraph** and it's value may be in any language(most preferable arabic).

In the .jrxml file I have set **ResourceBundle="i18n"** and in the textfield have used **$R{text1.paragraph}**

Now the problem is that when I run it from eclipse in the PDF file I get output of the field as **$R{text1.paragraph}** not it's value

Comment: Post a `.jrxml` file that illustrates the problem. Also, the project structure shows a `.java` file; where are the `.class` files? Where is the `.jasper` file? How is JasperReports being used to run the report (i.e., is it integrated with a web framework; if so, how)?

Comment: Thanks: - The resource bundle problem is solved but there is a new problem. I have arabic text in the properties file but in the reports it displays unknown characters not '?'.

Comment: @Dave: Do you have any hint about the arabic problem because if I use Arabic as staticField than it's displayed properly? So the problem is only for respurceBundle?

Comment: No idea, sorry. Post another StackOverflow question that describes the Arabic text problem.